# get "Missing CI config file" while no variables defined in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I did not set up any variable neither in my yaml file nor in my settings but I get "Missing CI config file" when I want to run my pipeline and also asks me to put the variable key and value while I did not define any variable in my settings.
Could you please help me with it ?

Comment: "Missing CI config file" message and add variable form are not related